# CNN model with zero-one-loss in TensorFlow 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I'm currently working on a project for a college exam in which it is required to develop a convolutional neural network for the binary classification of images. In the project specs it is also clearly specified that zero-one-loss should be used.

In the process of getting a baseline model to eventually do hyperparameter tuning, I'm getting stuck in fitting the model as it gives me an error if I try running it with zero-one-loss.

I'm defining the model like this:

```
def baseline_model_v0():
  img_shape = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, CHANNELS)
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=img_shape))
  
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(padding="same"))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(padding="same"))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(padding="same"))

  model.add(Flatten())

  model.add(Dense(units=512, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(units=512, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(units=512, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))

  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
                loss=zero_one_loss,
                metrics=METRICS)

  return model
```

where zero_one_loss is a custom loss function defined following TF documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#custom_losses)

```
def zero_one_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  res = 1.0 if y_true != y_pred else 0.0
  return res
```

However when I call the fit method I get an error:

```
model = baseline_model_v0()
history_v0 = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=30)

Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-3c67809f14c1> in <module>
      1 model = baseline_model_v0()
----> 2 history_v0 = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=30)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 997, in train_step
        self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 579, in minimize
        return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 689, in apply_gradients
        grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/utils.py", line 78, in filter_empty_gradients
        f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d_3/kernel:0', 'conv2d_3/bias:0', 'conv2d_4/kernel:0', 'conv2d_4/bias:0', 'conv2d_5/kernel:0', 'conv2d_5/bias:0', 'dense_4/kernel:0', 'dense_4/bias:0', 'dense_5/kernel:0', 'dense_5/bias:0', 'dense_6/kernel:0', 'dense_6/bias:0', 'dense_7/kernel:0', 'dense_7/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_3/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 64) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_3/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_4/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 128) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_4/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_5/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 128, 256) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_5/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_4/kernel:0' shape=(262144, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_4/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_5/kernel:0' shape=(512, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_5/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_6/kernel:0' shape=(512, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_6/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_7/kernel:0' shape=(512, 1) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_7/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>)).
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here please?

Comment: This function is not differentiable, have you wondered why nobody uses it as a loss?

Comment: Yeah, it was in fact my doubt but I wouldn't know how to be compliant with the request in the project statement otherwise

Comment: They probably made a mistake or they meant a different function.

Comment: I'll ask clarification about this cause it is very weird, I would use binary cross entropy for this...